# Show content from data in tooltip d3

Tags: javascript, d3.js, mouseevent, mouseover

I am following [this](http://plnkr.co/edit/JpVkqaZ1AmFdBbOMwMup?p=preview) example to add a tooltip to my circles, displayed on a map.

```
var tooltip = d3.select("body")
    .append("div")
    .attr("id", "mytooltip")
    .style("position", "absolute")
    .style("z-index", "10")
    .style("visibility", "hidden")
    .text("a simple tooltip");
```

Then Ive got this mouseover

```
// callbackfunction preparing the data
// then

var feature = g.selectAll("circle")
    .data(data.features)
    .enter()
    .append("circle")
//...

feature.on("mouseover",function(d) { 
    d3.select(this)
    .transition()
    .ease("elastic")
    .duration(500)
    .attr('r', function (d){ 
              return (d.features.xy);
          })
    d3.select("#mytooltip")
    .style("visibility", "visible")
    .text(function(d) {
        console.log(d.features.xy)
        return (d.features.xy)
     })
```

That does not display the value of `xy`.
Output of `console.log` is:

> TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'd.xy')

The Problem is obviously that with the `d3.select("#mytooltip")` statement I enter the `var tooltip` to which my `data.features...` is not bound to. How do I bind the circles to the mouseover (which are created in `var feature = g.selectAll("circle")`, after calling `d3.select`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.data` function is expecting an array, to be distributed among several elements ("data" is plural). If you want to give a single "piece of data" to a single element (namely, your `tooltip`), you need the `.datum` function:

```
tooltip.datum(myData)
```

Alternatively, you can do:

```
tooltip.data([myData])
```

In your original code, since you don't have the `tooltip` variable (nor, for that matter, `myData`), you can insert it in the **mouseover** event:

```
(...)
 d3.select("#mytooltip")
   .datum(d)
   .style("visibility", "visible")
(...)
```

---

Another option: you can draw the tooltip directly, without binding any data to it:

```
d3.select("#mytooltip")
   .style("visibility", "visible")
   .text(d.features.xy);
```

Here `d` still refers to the data of the object you are mouseover-ing, so this should work just as well.

Comment: Sorry, I used the line `.data(myData)` as a starting point: the last edit should make things clearer. Here the `myData` should actually be `d`.

Comment: Im still having troubles to follow. In the *declaration* of the variable `tooltip` I do not change anything, while in `d3.select("#mytooltip")` I simply add `datum(d)`?

Comment: Yes, that's just it.

Comment: Why wouldnt I need the `function(d) {....` in your last example? Where does d3 know where to get the data from?

Comment: .text() can take either the string to show, or a function turning the data into strings. The later is useful in a large selection when the strings from each element are different, but here you have a single element, and you know what string needs to be printed: it depends only on your circle's data. This data is fetched in the parameter `d` on the line `feature.on("mouseover",function(d) { `.

Comment: Could I access different elements within `text()`? so `d.features.xy1`, `d.features.xy2`...

Comment: You can refer to anything within the `text()` argument as if you were outside. You can make any complicated expression here, based on your local and global variables (`d`, `feature`, `d3`, etc.). If you need a several-lines computation (with a `for` loop or whatnot), you cannot easily do it within the function parenthesis: better to introduce a local variable, make the computation two lines above, and call your new variable in `text()`.